# Pydantic 2.0: Initializing a BaseModel with a private variable to be used to create computed_fields

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Using the following version

```ini
pydantic = "^2.0.2"
pydantic-settings = "^2.0.1"
```

Want to create a pydantic BaseModel for AWS SQS Messages, where the input is hidden after dumping the json via `print(model.model_dump_json())`

What I have without hidden / private attributes.

```py
class SQSMessage(BaseModel):

    message: dict

    @property
    def sub_msg(self) -> dict:
        return json.loads(self.message["Message"])

    @computed_field
    @property
    def message_id(self) -> str:
        return self.message["MessageId"]

    @computed_field
    @property
    def bucket(self) -> str:
        return self.sub_msg["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]

    @computed_field
    @property
    def key(self) -> str:
        return self.sub_msg["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]

    @computed_field
    @property
    def event_datetime(self) -> datetime:
        _dt = self.sub_msg["Records"][0]["eventTime"]
        if "Z" in _dt:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(self.sub_msg["Records"][0]["eventTime"].replace("Z", ""))
        else:
            return datetime.fromisoformat(self.sub_msg["Records"][0]["eventTime"])
```

This works well, but the messsage var is still shown when dumping the model json.

Example:

```py
msg = {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "0d69f2aa-3384-5435-b75a-a9102074b9a3",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678910:example-sns-topic",
        "Subject": "Amazon S3 Notification",
        "Message": '{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"2.1","eventSource":"aws:s3","awsRegion":"us-east-1",'
                   '"eventTime":"2022-10-07T11:46:55.304Z","eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",'
                   '"userIdentity":{"principalId":"AWS:AROARSMOKBLH3KNNAYOF2:ABCD12345@SOMEDOMAIN.com"},'
                   '"requestParameters":{"sourceIPAddress":"159.53.46.223"},'
                   '"s3":{"s3SchemaVersion":"1.0","configurationId":"tf-s3-topic-20220908215027661200000001",'
                   '"bucket":{"name":"app-bucket_name",'
                   '"ownerIdentity":{"principalId":"A1GXDFZQ55BKMX"},'
                   '"arn":"arn:aws:s3:::app-bucket_name"},'
                   '"object":{"key":"export/raw/v1/example.csv",'
                   '"size":0,'
                   '"eTag":"c258a1bafcdc3e550a13265867e8e5f4","sequencer":"00634011AF3640E697"}}}]}',
    }
model = SQSMessage(message=msg)
print(model.model_dump_json())
>>> {"message":{"Type":"Notification","MessageId":"0d69f2aa-3384-5435-b75a-a9102074b9a3","TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678910:example-sns-topic","Subject":"Amazon S3 Notification","Message":"{\"Records\":[{\"eventVersion\":\"2.1\",\"eventSource\":\"aws:s3\",\"awsRegion\":\"us-east-1\",\"eventTime\":\"2022-10-07T11:46:55.304Z\",\"eventName\":\"ObjectCreated:Put\",\"userIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"AWS:AROARSMOKBLH3KNNAYOF2:ABCD12345@SOMEDOMAIN.com\"},\"requestParameters\":{\"sourceIPAddress\":\"159.53.46.223\"},\"s3\":{\"s3SchemaVersion\":\"1.0\",\"configurationId\":\"tf-s3-topic-20220908215027661200000001\",\"bucket\":{\"name\":\"app-bucket_name\",\"ownerIdentity\":{\"principalId\":\"A1GXDFZQ55BKMX\"},\"arn\":\"arn:aws:s3:::app-bucket_name\"},\"object\":{\"key\":\"export/raw/v1/example.csv\",\"size\":0,\"eTag\":\"c258a1bafcdc3e550a13265867e8e5f4\",\"sequencer\":\"00634011AF3640E697\"}}}]}"},"message_id":"0d69f2aa-3384-5435-b75a-a9102074b9a3","bucket":"app-bucket_name","key":"export/raw/v1/example.csv","event_datetime":"2022-10-07T11:46:55.304000"}
```

When I try to use `PrivateAttrs`, like so

```py
...
   _message: dict = PrivateAttr(default_factory=dict)
...
model = SQSMessage(_message=msg)
print(model.model_dump_json())
>>> {}
```

This does hide the private attributes, however we are unable to reference this field to create computed_fields. How could this be achieved with pydantic 2?

EDIT:
I have also tried adding the following Config, but this does not hide the message field when dumping to json.

```py
    class Config:
        @staticmethod
        def json_schema_extra(schema: dict, _):
            props = {}
            for k, v in schema.get('properties', {}).items():
                if not v.get("hidden", False):
                    props[k] = v
            schema["properties"] = props

    message: dict = Field(hidden=True)
```

Comment: `message: dict = Field(exclude=True)` ? https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/fields/#exclude

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @MatsLindh from the comments.

```py
message: dict = Field(exclude=True)
```